# @yield same header and footer across many webpages using only 1 include webpage

Tags: php, laravel

i have only 1 page named include.blade.php and it contains the @section for header, footer and navbar ONLY. i want to use this page so everytime i make a webpage, i just call it. so i @yield-ed it into another page (index.blade.php) and works super fine. but when i also @yield it to another page named (grades.blade.php) it shows the index.blade.php webpage and the grade.blade.php. so the browser appends 2 webpage in a single browser window. how do i have a single include.blade.php having the footers and headers i need in every single pages and just @yield it everywhere or it is not possible to have just one?

my code in include.blade.php:

```
@extends('index')
@section('footer')<footer class="section" ><div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6  col-sm-6 ">
          <p>
            <br> © Copyright Pgasinan 2015
            <br>ArelStreet,
            <br>Dagupa 2400
            <br>Phs
          </p>
        </div></div></div></footer>@endsection




@section('navbar')<div class="navbar navbar-default" id="mynav"><div class="container"><div class="navbar-header" >
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-ex-collapse">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" id="brand"><span>Univean</span></a>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-ex-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#sec1">Academics</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#faq">FAQs</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/login">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> @endsection

@section('cssandjs')
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue resides from your extending index at the top of your template.  You shouldn't be  extending a full layout on an "include" page.

It seems to be you should have two (or possibly more) layout templates, like index, and in those templates you can include the "include" page.  Then for grades, you just extend the new layout instead of index.  You shouldn't have to worry about including the header, footer, and navbar within your pages.  They should just simply extend a layout.

Read further at https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade

Comment: thanks! i still dont get it. i saw the @extends in the laravel website and it is my basis.

Comment: do you know some video reference using many webpages having only 1 "incude" page like so

Comment: Laracasts has many video tutorials for Laravel, although I do not know if they have one that explains your issue.  `@extends` is used to specify a "master" layout you could say.  That layout defines the sections, those sections are filled by the pages.  So while you can use `@include`, includes really aren't what you want to be thinking about with blade, you want to think about extending layouts.  I think if you take the time to read the link I posted and view several examples online, you'll start to understand.  Read it thoroughly and practice.

Comment: thanks! i got it now. i just used @include and yielded the section names as youve said.